# Pass data onClick event to the function in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I create my component in the parent component this way:

```
renderRow(row){
  var Buttons = new Array(this.props.w)
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.w; i++) {
    var thisButton=<FieldButton handler={this.actionFunction} key={'row'+ row +'col'+ i}></FieldButton>
    Buttons.push(thisButton)
  }
  return Buttons
}

renderField(){
  var Field = new Array(this.props.h);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.h; i++) {
    var row = this.renderRow(i);
    Field.push(<View key={i} style={styles.fieldWrap}>{row}</View>);
  }
  this.setState({field: Field})
}
```

**The Goal:**

I have to change the state of the FieldButton component.

**My question:**

What is the right way to change the Childs component state?

**First Attempt:**

I tried to bind a prop to the state of the parent component:

```
 <FieldButton color={this.state.color} handler={this.actionFunction} key={'row'+ row +'col'+ i}></FieldButton>
```

I also implemented the componentWillReceiveProps Method but it was never called.

I tried to move the child outside of the for loop and it worked.

**Second Attempt:**

I tried to use refs: [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734401/array-of-components-with-refs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case, seems to be caused due to closure. You should make use of `let` for the for loop, otherwise everytime forLoop will call `this.renderRow(i)` with the `this.props.h.length - 1` and similary in your renderRow case as well

```
renderRow(row){
  var Buttons = new Array(this.props.w)
  for (let i = 0; i < this.props.w; i++) {
    let thisButton=<FieldButton handler={this.actionFunction} key={'row'+ row +'col'+ i}></FieldButton>
    Buttons.push(thisButton)
  }
  return Buttons
}

renderField(){
  var Field = new Array(this.props.h);
  for (let i = 0; i < this.props.h; i++) {
    let row = this.renderRow(i);
    Field.push(<View key={i} style={styles.fieldWrap}>{row}</View>);
  }
  this.setState({field: Field})
}
```

After this since, your Parent component already holds the state, you could pass it as props and then implement `componentWillReceiveProps`.

> P.S. However if your child component state is directly derivable from
>   props, you should directly use the props instead of keeping a local
>   state in child

Comment: if you want you can answer the linked question. Your answer would fit there very well.

Comment: Glad the answer helped you.  Its, fine that you could yourself add an answer to the linked question or maybe delete it. Cheers